# Is it possible to get last modified date for certain field?

Tags: entities, nodes

Is it perhaps possible to get date and time of last modification of certain field?

Just like in table "Node" you have "created" and "modified" dates, but what about fields of certain content type?

I would like to know when certain field was last modified.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the field_data_xxx and field_revision_xxx tables and there is no time stamp field, which means you wont be able to get the last modified dates for fields.

You can probably use [Field Attach API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/group/field_attach/7) to add time entries to a custom table which will contain field_key, entity id, bundle id and time-stamp columns.